# In transaction insert same key for two tables (1. primary 2. foreign)

Tags: php, mysql

I have in this code 2 queries. (in my real code I have 6 queries and I need transaction).

I don't know how to get variable `$category_id` cause that category isn't putted yet in database (it should be inserted in same time - all or nothing)

code:

```
try {
    $this->mysqli->begin_transaction();

    $this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `category` (`name`) VALUES ('$category')");
    $this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `subcategory` (`name`,`category_id` ) VALUES ('$subcategory','$category_id')");

    $this->mysqli->commit();

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    $this->mysqli->rollBack();
}
```

mysql tables:

```
    category:
    ---------
    |id|name|

    subcategory:
    |id|name|category_id|
```

So I need some solution how to know before query what is the value of `$category_id`, or how to modify query so category_id in database is filed.

Answer (score 1):

[`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is what you want here.

```
try {
    $this->mysqli->begin_transaction();

    $this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `category` (`name`) VALUES ('$category')");
    $this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `subcategory` (`name`,`category_id` ) VALUES ('$subcategory', LAST_INSERT_ID())");

    $this->mysqli->commit();

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    $this->mysqli->rollBack();
}
```

P.S.  Look into prepared statements, instead of concatenating variables into your query.